# .htaccess is concatenating rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)\/([0-9]*)\/?$ ler.php?categoria=$1&id=$2
```

this is working for http://www.domain.com/frases/13571/

The point is that I need to redirect all **HTTP** to **HTTPS** after this  rule is already applied.

So I write this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)\/([0-9]*)\/?$ ler.php?categoria=$1&id=$2
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But isn't working like I supposed to. I'm getting this when I perform a HTTP request:
https://www.domain.com/frases/13571/?categoria=frases&id=13571

What is the right code that just change the protocols without modify the others parts of url?
I think that my code is doing 2 requests in the first rules and that is generating this wrong url.

Comment: Just switching the order of the rules – external rewrite to HTTPS if HTTP first, internal rewrite second – should be sufficient already.

Comment: As above - you need to do your 301 redirect to https first

Comment: @CBroe This generate a slow server behavior. I have 30 more rules like this one in the line 3 and before the HTTPS condition.

Comment: The server has to parse and test the rules in any case. And a quick check to determine _“hey is this an HTTPS connection or not?”_ should cost next to nothing … I seriously doubt that this has any real performance implications.

Comment: @CBroe But the rule need to be executed with or without the HTTPS. If I put the condition first so on the HTTP this will not work. Thank you.

Comment: The following rules _will_ get executed on the next run, _after_ the browser has requested the new HTTPS URL …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L` flag must be applied to your rewrite rule.
You can use this code instead

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /ler.php?categoria=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Note:

- you don't need to escape slashes (`\/` can be `/`)
- you'll need to clear your browser's cache before trying again with this code. Your old rule is now in cache and you won't see the new code working if you don't clear it.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

You rewrite from the original `REQUEST_URI`, the current is what you have captured, so try:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://$1 [R=301,L]
```

If not working, rewrite log could be useful.

Comment: `chain` was not a good idea. I have proposed an another answer.